# How to display generic parameter arguments in xml documentation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I can reference a generic type/method definition like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a <see cref="Func{T}"/>.
/// </summary>
public void Method<T>(Func<T> func) { }
```

However this does not work:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a <see cref="Func{Int32}"/>.
/// </summary>
public void Method(Func<int> func) { }
```

ReSharper / the generated help file says `Func<TResult>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you are specifying the type of the `cref` attribute as a type: `Func<T>`. This is an exact match for a type in the `System` namespace. We need to create a link to the documentation for that type: [`Func<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx). It is easy to find and link to. Note that this produces one link to one type.

In the second example, when you look for the type `Func<Int32>`, that is not really a type with documentation you could point to. The type in the `System` namespace is generic and takes a parameter. You might not think of it as an exact match, but the parser makes the assumption that `Int32` is the name you are using for the type parameter, and that you want to point to the type it can easily find in the `System` namespace. Again, this produces one link to one type that you actually can find in the System namespace.

You probably want to create a reference that uses two links to two types, like is done on the [Enumerable.Sum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535184(v=vs.110).aspx) reference page. For this method,

```
public static int Sum<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource,int> selector
)
```

they documented the parameter selection using two links:

> Type: [System.Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)<TSource, [Int32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32(v=vs.110).aspx)>

Here, they have a reference to two types, not one. One of the links looks like it is a reference to the delegate group `System.Func`(which is again not a type with documentation we can point to), but it actually points to the `System.Func<T,TResult>` delegate's documentation. The other link is to `System.Int32`.

You can do this if you get more formal. The xml passes compiler verification and is unchanged if you use

```
<see cref="T:System.Func{T:System.Int32}"/>
```

However, I don't know how that will display in most templates. It's what is used to document Entity Framework source code. For an example (that does not display nicely), you can look at the documentation for the [System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.core.common.commandtrees.expressionbuilder(v=vs.113).aspx).

I have also seen it done with

```
<see cref="T:System.Func &lt; T:System.Int32 &gt;"/>
```

Again, ignoring the template to display it nicely and only going by the xml, this produce markup that passes compiler syntax verification. You might have better luck when you transform this from xml to create your actual documentation.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I am trying to do (maybe with another attribute)?

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to do what I think you want to do.